# jQuery getting object value from <li> and change <li> class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div`:

```
<div id="ddDistr" class="searchBoxSortDistrict" tabindex="1">
  <ul id="ddd">
  </ul>
</div>
```

and in it I put html from `json`:

```
$("#ddd").html(" "), $.each(dis, function(
  index, value) {
    $("#ddd").append( "<li><a style=\"cursor: pointer;\">"
    + value.fieldName + "("
    + value.count + ")</a></li>");
   }
);
```

I want to change `onclick <li>` class to `.active`.

```
$('#ddDistr li > a').click(function() {
  console.log('dd');
  $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

But it doesn't work, where is problem in my code?

Also I want to get `value.fieldName` from active `<li>` element and parse it to `POST`.

How can I get it ?

Comment: what is `.changeDist`???

Comment: updated, I pasted wrong code

Comment: Look into jQuery's event delegation with `.on()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used click event for anchor element. `$(this).siblings('li')` wont work as li are not siblings of anchor. you need to use  something like `$(this).closest('li').siblings('')`.

**Update:** You will also need event delegation for attaching events to dynamically generated element

For adding the class to clicked anchors parent li:

```
$('#ddDistr').on('click', 'li > a',function() {
    console.log('dd');
    $(this).closest('li').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

for adding class to clicked anchor tag:

```
$('#ddDistr').on('click', 'li > a',function() {
  console.log('dd');
  $(this).closest('li').siblings().find('a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: if I wrote <li> code by hand it's working for $('#ddd li > a'), also changing class attr of #ddd, but from generated code it dosent work

Comment: @kxyz: you should also store fieldName as some attribute value. that way you can get it using `.attr()`. otherwise you will need regex to remove the braces and its inner content to get fieldvalue.

Answer (score 2):

`li` is not a sibling of `a`, it's its parent.

This is clear when you look at `li > a`.

Simply change your code so it uses `parent()`:

```
$(this).parent().removeClass('active');
```

Or assign the click handler to the actual `li`.

Also as  j08691 suggested, [read about](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using `.on()` and event delegation. If you're defining your click handler before you're generating your markup, it won't work, because you're only assigning the click handler to existing content. That's why you want to delegate the events to a container that already exists.